# Is "outcome" plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Our participation will ensure that the outcome of the meetings are compatible with the interests of the U.S. for transportation and classification of XXX materials.

Comment: In a word, no.  Multiple meetings -> multiple possible outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Outcome is singular. My guess is they made the mistake of doing number agreement with the plural noun “meetings.” This is an error because the noun phrase is “outcome of the meetings” which is singular.

The issue is what noun is the subject. In ghis case if is outcome.

Edit for your comments: If you use “outcomes,” yes use “are.” If you use “technical work” use “is” because “work” is single.

Comment: I'll go with: "Our participation will ensure that the outcomes of the meetings are compatible with the interests of the U.S. for transportation and classification of XXX materials."

Comment: One more; are or is?  "The technical work done at these meetings is an import precursor to the..."